# CPUMON mhz reading weird

Tags: cpu-speed, speedstep

I am using this cpu usage monitor: http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=cpumon. They give a cpu speed monitor (im assuming to monitor speedstep). However when the computer is idle it seems to be incorrect. See screenshot with cpuz and the monitor. Is this because CPUMON is monitoring something else (maybe cstates)?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean "the computer is idle"?  Just because you are not running something does not mean the OS is busy doing things.  There are many background processes that are being done.  Yes the CPUMON takes some cpu time to collect and display the data. Part of that is how often it samples and displays the data and how efficient it is.

Comment: Did you try asking the developer on his forum?